# Single responsability Principle and Repository

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern, solid-principles

Despite googling quite a bit I could not find a clear answer to my doubts.

I am trying to apply "SOLID" whenever I can and try to use common sense and avoid a pattern when I see that a pattern is creating more problems than it's trying to solve.I dont want to apply a pattern and make life difficult for somebody else using my code just for the sake "I write patterns" if you see what I mean..

Now I am struggling with one of the principles that I thought was the easiest to grasp "SRP"

How do you pratically apply this principles to repositories?

Lets suppose I have a

1. IEmployeeRepository
2. IUserRepository
3. IProductRepository

and commonly they will have methods like theses

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUser(int id);
    IEnumerable<User> GetAllUser();
    void DeleteUser(int id);
}
```

same for employees and products.

Are we saying that each of these method should be a class on it's own? even though at times we are talking a single line of code?

any suggestions or sample app anywhere would be much appreciated.

many thanks

Comment: Probably better here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a hard time figuring out the limits of the *Single Responsibility Pattern* then you can instead go looking for obvious examples of classes that do not use SRP. E.g., a class that implements business rules for users as well as configuring the backup of the user database and by the way also some special logging to a file that it publicly exposes because it is a rather neat hack. You should definitely avoid that.

One of the reasons that you seem to be able to apply SRP all the way so that each method can go in a separate class could be because you have an *Anaemic Domain Model*. Perhaps your application simply exposes CRUD operations on top of a database and there are no real business rules implemented in your application?

In any case it is not applying SRP to split `UserRepository` into a class for each method but that you even get this idea could be a sign that `UserRepository` does not really have any purpose in you architecture.

Answer (score 1):

For basic CRUD operations, it's common to use a generic repository :

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
   T Get(int id);
   IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
   T Update(T item)
   void Delete(int id);
}
```

or similar.  Then your concrete implementations can inherit from one base.

Comment: HI I actually do have a generic repository but that still does not answer the question in a way

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the level of abstraction.

//object with some behavior : Persistence model + behavior 
`Class Cat {
string Name {get;set;}
void Meov(){...}
}`

//object with some behavior

```
SomeRepository:ISomeRepository{
User GetUser(int id);
IEnumerable<User> GetAllUser();
void DeleteUser(int id);
```

}

This is interesting :)
http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

https://blog.inf.ed.ac.uk/sapm/2014/02/04/the-anaemic-domain-model-is-no-anti-pattern-its-a-solid-design/

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on where you set the scope for a "Single Responsibility". In my opinion, you could split this up by saying:

- Every repository has the single responsibility to manage only one type of entities. That means all methods in your `UserRepository` should be related to `User` entities but not to other ones (like Products). That means there should not be any methods in your `UserRepository` like `GetProducts` or something similar.
- Every method within a repository should also have its single responsibility. That means that every method should only handle one specific case (like Creating, Deleting etc...).

In that way you would still fulfill the SRP principle (depending on its surrounding context) without having to create a class for every function (which seems to be a bit overkill in my opinion).